# How to setup cloud-watch alarm for s3 bucket if no data is received in bucket for 5 or 10 minutes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an s3 bucket where at every 3 min one tar file is getting uploaded. Now I want to set up alarm notification if s3 file does not receive any data for 5 min I should get notified by an email. Unfortunately I am unable to find any such metrics in cloud-watch s3. Please let me know if anyone has solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch has a `NumberOfObjects` metric for every Amazon S3 bucket.

However, I'm not sure how often it is updated. It certainly wouldn't have 5-minute resolution.

Plus, there is no Alarm that means "if this number has not changed".

If your bucket does not have many objects (eg < 1000), one approach would be:

- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The **Lambda function** would call `list_bucket()` to retrieve a list of objects from the bucket, then sort by `LastModified`
- If it has been more than *x* minutes since a new file, then trigger a notification

If the bucket has *many* objects, then:

- Create an **Amazon S3 Event** to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever an object *is* added to the bucket

  - The Lambda function should **update a database** (eg DynamoDB) with the current timestamp
- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to trigger an AWS Lambda function

  - The **Lambda function** would retrieve the timestamp from the database and compare it to the current time
  - If it has been more than *x* minutes since a new file was added, then trigger a notification

Comment: How about creating a cloudwatch log metric and create alarm from that metric?

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan There is no alarm that can trigger on "metric not changed for past _x_ minutes".

Comment: How about setting the alarm when one or more data points missing

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan There is no alarm that can trigger on "data points missing".

Comment: Looks like we can, if the missing data points to be treated as "breaching". Am i understanding it wrong. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data

Comment: @ArunmainthanKamalanathan I don't think that is relevant to this use-case, but please try it and let us know what you find.